# ASP.NET Core 6.0 migration error: Certificate chain was issued by an untrusted authority

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ssms, database-connection

I have recently started coding on a new device and am encountering a problem with the connection string during migration.

When running `Update-Database`, I get the following error if I don't use the `TrustServerCertificate=True`:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

Previously I never had to use `TrustServerCertificate=True`. I understand that there is a problem with some type of certificate and I might need to add some configuration but not really sure what exactly is the issue google isn't helping much with this issue either so I was hoping maybe this place could help me with this.

The following is my connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": 
{
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DollarStoreAmazonDB;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"  
}
```

I tried refreshing ssms, tried changing few settings in ssms but to no avail.